# Creating a Google App Engine datastore entity without initializing a particular property

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I have a `Class` entity, which has the properties `name`, and `students`.I want to first of all create the entity then add values to the student property afterwards.But i am not sure how to do this.I have tried `null` (forgive me if this is an abomination, am new to Python) but it returns an error message.This is my `Class` definition

```
class Class(ndb.Model):
     name = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
     students = ndb.KeyProperty(repeated=True) 
     ...
```

And the handler for my Class Model

```
class ClassHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def post(self):
    name=self.request.get('class_name')
    callback = self.request.get('callback')
    class = class.get_by_id(name)
    if class:
        self.error(409)
    else:
        n = self.request.get('class_name')
        class=Class(id=n, class_name=n, members) #<<<---//this is where am stuck
        team.put()
        if callback:
            self.response.write(callback + '(' + team.toJSON() + ')')
        else:
            self.response.write(team.toJSON())
```

I spent the past couple of hours on Google looking for a solution.Any suggestion on what i need to do would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** This is the error message i get when i try to use `null`
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A big +1 to everything @akgill said.

As to your specific problem, you do not need to provide any properties at Entity instantiation, or you can provide some or all.

I am not sure what you are referring to when you are talking about "null" or None.

Any way to add students you need to provide a list of students in the constructor call, or use append

```
cls = Class()
cls.students.extend([list of student keys])x
```

Comment: I have had it all mixed up. You were right I do not need to provide any values for entities at instantiation.This confusion arose because when I created the entity without initializing the `members` property, that property didn't show up in the datastore in the list of available properties for my Class entity, just the one I initialized.

Comment: Yep, the datastore will only store inititialised properties (with a default value, or supplied value)

Comment: In your example, did you mean `extend` or `append`

Comment: When add a list to a list you use extend, if you are adding a single item to the list then use append.  Have a read of the docs for list methods.

Answer (score 1):

- Okay, first of all `class` is a protected word in python and you should **not** be naming your variable `class`.  When you do this, you are locally overwriting the meaning of the word `class` to Python.  Also, you seem to be doing `class.get_by_id(name)`.  Do you mean `Class.get_by_id(name)`?  That would be the correct syntax if `get_by_id(argument)` were a method from your `Class` class.
- **Secondly, you should post the trace that you get out with the error message in order to get help on your problem.**
- I think you can just declare `Class()` without any parameters and it will achieve what you are going for.  It will create the Class object without any of the parameters specified and you can specify them later.

#### Example:

```py
class ClassHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def post(self):
    name=self.request.get('class_name')
    callback = self.request.get('callback')
    the_class = Class.get_by_id(name)
    if not the_class:
        self.error(409)
    else:
        n = self.request.get('class_name')
        the_class = Class()
        team.put()
        if callback:
            self.response.write(callback + '(' + team.toJSON() + ')')
        else:
            self.response.write(team.toJSON())
```

#### The changes I have made to what you had:

1. I've changed variable name `class` to `the_class` everywhere.
2. I've changed your instantiation of the variable class so you have `Class.get_by_id(name)` which is the correct syntax for calling that method, associated with ndb.Model, inherited by `Class`
3. I've changed your if statement to `if not the_class`.  Is that what you wanted?  Otherwise, I'm confused about what's going on there.
4. In the else statement, you can see I've just declared `the_class = Class()` which I think is what you were asking about

Comment: Thanks for the tips.But how do i use `None` when i have already declared `members=ndb.KeyProperty(repeated=True)` ?

Comment: I've looked at it more now and concluded that my suggestions about using `__init__` were wrong.  I'll amend my post.  However, you should still put your trace and error in your post, otherwise it is very difficult to help you find your error.

Comment: I have edited the question to include the trace, i didn't include it before because the error message seems pretty straightforward.